# About Network Connections on Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm neither good nor experienced about asking questions so i hope I'm not doing it wrong. ( Also pardon my English as it's not my native language) But here is one thing still bothering me even after a few night of googling ;

Someone asked me about a project on Windows Mobile but as a newbie .Net developer and cell-phone illiterate person ; I have doubts about its possibility. I searched a lot , but still can't be sure about it ; and unfortunately i don't have much time left to turn back and answer ; so i had to ask if this scenario is possible. ( it's not a business thing by the way , my old teacher from university asked as a favor , so no money involved. just saying.)

Now we have a **Device A** and a **WinMo Phone** in close distance and a **server far away**. The main idea is to transfer some data from **Device A to Phone** , view and maybe process the data and then **send all those to the server far away**.

View&Process data and send the data over 3G or something , should be easy. I'm pretty certain about that. My problem is connecting Device A and phone. They said , they were planing a cable connection between devices ( shame on me i have no idea about that kind of connections ) but they may also use wireless if they can attach 802.11 to Device A. I haven't asked them yet but bluetooth may be another choice.

So ;

1) Is it possible to connect the phone to Device A via a cable and get data.  Frankly i have no idea how cable connections works on phones. I searched about it but all i can find is "Connecting to Computer" stuff.

2) Is it possible to connect over wireless ( 802.11 / Tcp )? I do searched about this ; and it can be done as far as i know ; but i also heard there a some limitation in WinMo in different matters ( ie. packet capturing ) , so not quite sure now. It's a compact framework after all , may not be as flexible/strong as normal one.

Bluetooth should be no problem , i haven't really searched about it but i have little doubt about it.

Any kind of article , documentation etc is extremely welcome. Normally I love reading documentation and doing my own searches but unfortunately in this situation i don't even have a starting point ( and time ) for it. Once i knew it's possible and it's not a task beyond my level ; i'll have lots of time to read/search/develop.

Ah by the way , i have the luxury to choose the phone ( WinMo 5 or **6** or maybe even 7 ) and the language ( C# ) i prefer.

Thanks for your time and answers in advance.

Comment: why have you marked this a community wiki?

Comment: as i'm not good or experienced in this topic , I thought it would be better to keep editing barrier low so that anyone can fix many possible mistakes in the main post. I thought that was the point but now that you questioned it , maybe i should have read more than the tool tip about it before posting.

Comment: you might be able to edit it and change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by evaluating the [Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23217).

[Microsoft Sync Framework Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/)

[Sync Framework Team Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sync/)

Comment: Oh looks like just the thing I'm looking for. Looking deeper into it now , thanks.